# Spark job failed due to "Could not execute broadcast in 300 secs."

Tags: sql, apache-spark, beeline

My scheduled job excuted everyday at 2:20 AM, but it occasionally failed. Beeline log in spark is shown below.

```
21/02/10 02:20:27 INFO DAGScheduler: ResultStage 14825 ($anonfun$withThreadLocalCaptured$1 at FutureTask.java:266) failed in 299.939 s due to Job 4879 cancelled part of cancelled job group a56640d0-f296-4ca4-bd10-783e34d3939c
21/02/10 02:20:27 ERROR BroadcastExchangeExec: Could not execute broadcast in 300 secs.
```

What's the meaning of `Job 4879 cancelled part of cancelled job group a56640d0-f296-4ca4-bd10-783e34d3939c`?

Comment: Did you find the solution for this?